# Передать параметр в контроллер из формы

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf, controller

У меня есть форма, в которую выводятся данные, и мне нужно по нажатию например на ссылку, чтобы сработал метод в контроллере, и туда передался в качестве параметра name конкретного выводимого объекта. Но при нажатии на ссылку Edit,я получаю

```
Could not parse as expression: "/request/${request.getName()}"
```

```html
<div class="row mb-2" >
    <th:div class="col-md-6" th:each="request : ${list}">
        <div class="col p-4 d-flex flex-column position-static">
            <h3 class="mb-0" th:text="${request.name}"></h3>
            <a class="stretched-link" th:href="/request/${request.getName()}">Edit</a>
        </div>    
        </div>
    </th:div>
```

---

```java
@GetMapping("/request/{name}")
public RequestEntity editRequest(@PathVariable String name) throws RequestException {
    RequestEntity requestEntity = new RequestEntity();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thymeleaf ожидает от вас одно из стандартных [выражений](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#standard-expression-syntax)
*(желательно выражение для формирования [URL](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html))*

Вы же передаёте ему строку, которую он не может понять, работающую по непонятным для него правилам.

**Из вышеприведенных ссылок в документации можно понять, что:**

- для формирования URL используются выражения `@{ ... }`
- для работы с переменными используются выражения `${ ... }`
- для работы с параметризованными запросами в URL используются выражения вида:
   `@{/order/{id}/details(id=3,action='show_all')}`

В итоге мы можем использовать выражение для формирования URL, использовать плейсхолдер для передачи параметра и в качестве параметра указать выражение переменной.

**В итоге получится:**

```
 th:href="@{/request/{name}(name=${request.getName()})}"
```

**Ссылки:**

- [Синтаксис стандартных выражений Thymeleaf](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#standard-expression-syntax)
- [Синтаксис для формирования URL в Thymeleaf](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html)